# Bedeutungen von "angehen"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich bin kein deutscher Muttersprachler. Als ich mir die Bedeutungen von "angehen" in Wörterbüchern angesehen habe, ist bei mir eine Frage aufgekommen, wie es in der Bedeutung "zu brennen beginnen" verwendet wird. In vielen Quellen habe ich Beispiele wie "Feuer ist angegangen" gefunden, aber nirgendwo habe ich Konstruktionen wie "das Benzin ist angegangen" gesehen, obwohl dieser Satz ebenfalls der so formulierten Bedeutung entspricht. Wann benutzt man tatsächlich "angehen" in einer solchen Bedeutung? Könnt ihr bitte noch Beispiele davon machen, außer dem Satz über Feuer?

Answer (score 6):

Die Bedeutung von "angehen" in "Das Feuer ist angegangen", ist weniger "beginnen zu brennen", als "gestartet werden", "aktiviert werden" oder auch "von sich aus starten".

Idiomatisch ist zum Beispiel die Verwendung mit elektrischen Geräten oder Maschinen:

- "Das Licht ging an."
- "Der Fernseher ging an."
- "Der Rasenmäher ging an."

Deswegen findet man keine Verwendungsbeispiele wie *"das Benzin ist angegangen". Denn das Benzin ist keine Gerätschaft die man in Gang setzen kann, sondern eine brennbare Substanz.

Dass "angehen" mit Feuer verwendet werden kann, ist vermutlich darauf zurückzuführen, dass das Feuer als Herdfeuer oder Lagerfeuer etwas ist, das man verwendet.

Um auszurücken, dass eine Substanz (in der Regel unabsichtlich oder von selbst) angefangen hat zu brennen verwendet man "sich entzünden", zum Beispiel: "Das Benzin hat sich entzündet.".

Answer (score 2):

Diese Bedeutung  ist umgangssprachlich, vergleiche [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/angehen), Bedeutung 3, das heißt, es gibt meist besser passende Verben. "Zu brennen beginnen" trifft nicht den Kern, es ist mehr ein *Übergang in den "Ein"-Zustand* oder ganz allgemein synonym zu *anfangen*.

Typischerweise geht Licht an, eine Kontrollleuchte, oder das Display eines Geräts.

Daneben alle Geräte, die man aufwändiger in Betrieb nehmen muss, wie Kaminfeuer oder ein Motorrad.

Für die allgemeine Bedeutung *anfangen* sind häufige Kombinationen: Film, Theatervorstellung.

Comment: @aldin Hierzu musst du auch wissen, dass man bei "Glühbirnen", "Displays" etc. zwar vom "Brennen" spricht, aber nicht unbedingt etwas wortwörtlich brennen muss, also kein Feuer gemeint sein muss. Es kann ein Glühdraht, eine LED, o.ä. sein, trotzdem spricht man vom "Brennen".

Answer (score 1):

Mit *»brennen«* ist in diesem Kontext keine offene Flamme gemeint, sondern das Leuchten einer Lichtquelle. Ein Beispiel:

> Die Taschenlampe brennt.

Dieser Satz bedeutet nicht, dass lodernde Flammen aus dem Gerät schlagen, die es in einen schwarzen verkohlten Klumpen verwandeln. Der Satz bedeutet vielmehr, dass die Taschenlampe Licht ausstrahlt und die Umgebung erhellt. Das Verb *»brennen«* wird in dieser Bedeutung verwendet, weil vor Erfindung elektrischer Lichtquellen jede Lampe nur dadurch funktionierte, dass in ihr ein Brennstoff verbrannt wurde. Die Lampe (oder zumindest ein Teil davon) musste tatsächlich brennen um Licht zu spenden. Als es dann elektrische Lampen gab, behielt man das Verb *»brennen«* aber bei wenn man eigentlich *»leuchten«* meinte.

> Das Licht geht an.

Damit ist gemeint, dass eine vorher dunkle Lichtquelle nun tatsächlich beginnt Licht auszusenden. Das Verb *»angehen«* wird hier aus der Welt der Motoren und Maschinen entlehnt, die bei Inbetriebnahme schon *angingen* bevor elektrisches Licht erfunden wurde.

Answer (score -3):

Benzin ist eine junge Erfindung von Carl Benz und irrelevant für die weitere Historique.

> Wann benutzt man tatsächlich "angehen" in einer solchen Bedeutung?

Tatsächlich überhaupt nicht. Deine Fragestellung ist einem Irrtum aufgesessen, weil die icksbeliebige Rechtschreibung nicht eindeutig ist. *An gehen* ist offensichtlich mit *ein schalten* verwandt, Trennung entsprechend älterer Rechtschreibung, Diphtonisierung teils wegen Betonung teils wegen unterschiedlicher Wurzel. So ist bspw. *angegangenes* (gammeliges) offensichtlich zu *eingehen* ("welken") zu stellen mit urindogermanischer Wurzel **neK-* "to die" womit es dem ingvaeonischen Sprachkreis zu zu rechnen ist.

Demgegenüber ist *ein-* i.S.v. brennen mit lateinisch *ignition* zu vergleichen, urindoger. **Hngwis*.

Während die Rekonstruktionsgeschichte zweifelhaft bleibt, man vergleiche etwa *anafallen* "angreifen" mit hebräisch*  *nafal* "fallen" – sacrebleu – ist es unnütz sich an oberflächlicher – *synchronischer* – Herleitung zu versuchen ist unnütz.

S.a. *engine* vs. *ingenuity*